# Pathfinder: Does Mystic Theurge allow me to use arcane spell slots for domain spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I've been thinking of the next Pathfinder character I have to make, and I decided on a [Mystic Theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge).

After doing some research, I decided to use the [Ecclesitheurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo---cleric-archetypes/ecclesitheurge) cleric archetype to satisfy the divine requirement, and [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist) for the arcane requirement. I have not yet looked into domains, subdomains, arcanist archetypes, or feats because I want to know if this is a viable idea before continuing.

From the Ecclesitheurge:

> At 1st level, when an ecclesitheurge chooses his cleric domains, he designates one as his primary domain and the other as his secondary domain. **An ecclesitheurge can use his non-domain spell slots to prepare spells from his primary domain's spell list**.

From the Mystic Theurge:

> **A mystic theurge can prepare and cast spells from one of his spellcasting classes using the available slots from any of his other spellcasting classes.** Spells prepared or cast in this way take up a slot one level higher than they originally occupied.

And finally, the Arcanist:

> An arcanist must prepare her spells ahead of time, but unlike a wizard, her spells are not expended when they're cast. **Instead, she can cast any spell that she has prepared consuming a spell slot of the appropriate level**, assuming she hasn't yet used up her spell slots per day for that level

Will this combination let me use arcane spell slots for domain spells?

For example, suppose I have Fire as my primary domain. Am I able to sacrifice a 4th level arcane spell slot to treat it as 3rd level divine spell slot (via Mystic Theurge), to then prepare Fireball via the Fire domain's domain spell?

Conversely, am I able to sacrifice a 2nd level cleric slot to prepare and additional 1st level wizard spell (such as Magic Missile), which is then usable via my arcanist's spells/day?

Comment: @Miniman agreed, and there doesn't seem to be consistency between the titular question of "What are my options?" and the body question of "are there any interesting quirks {from this stuff}?", so I'm wondering if this question might be trying to get at something else rather than just find out about quirks (for whatever people interpret as being 'quirks' as opposed to something like 'intended functions')

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: @KRyan: If I did my math correctly, by level 20 I should end up with 9th level spells in one discipline, and 7th level spells in the other. The tradeoff is that I lose out on the class features, channel, etc for extra flexibility. Even without greater (or any) exploits, the arcanist feels like a sorcerer without bloodlines, but with the flexibility of a wizard to me; the exploits are just gravy.

Comment: I recommend the discussion re: viability of the theurge should be taken to a chat room, lest the messages be deleted mid discussion. (Even if they're kept around just long enough in comments, they'll be kept around forever for future reference in a chat room!)

Comment: Especially considering this 'discussion' (or rather, rant) happens on every question or answer mentioning the Mystic Theurge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast domain spells in your arcane slots with just Mystic Theurge, you don't need the other stuff.  If you have a level in arcanist, you can use it just as you say.  Be aware you cannot use it with your cleric spells, even cleric spells prepared in Arcanist slots, as the arcanist ability applies only to spells prepared as an arcanist (even if they are in a different spell slot type).